# Best way to store messages sent to Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, event-handling, azureservicebus

I want to use Azure Service Bus Pub/Sub for some inter-service communications.  However, I want to have the ability to review those messages in the future even after they have been retrieved and mark as completed for troubleshooting purposes or for some historical analysis.  What would be the best way to go about doing that?  I thought about using Logic App to subscribe to Service Bus and store those messages in Cosmos DB, but I would have to do it per topic.  That is obviously not a scalable solutions. Any other suggested approach or another service that can do the same thing?  I briefly looked out at Event Hub but delivery is not guaranteed.

Comment: What's the nature of your topics? Are those set once and not changing? Or changing frequently? If so, do you have any control over their creation? At the end of the day, you're looking at the datastore selection and the needs that you have. Based on your needs you will qualify or disqualify the candidates. EventHub is **not** the right approach IMO (BTW, it's guarateed). CosmosDB, Storage Tables, Azure SQL, event Azure Montior with extended retention. It all boils down to your requirements.

Comment: The topics should change infrequently if at all, but I do see myself adding new topics when needed more frequently.  Yes, I will have control over their creations.  One possibility is to create a library and ensure that all my services uses it.  That library would be responsible for not only sending that message to the Azure Service Bus, but also to persist it to another store [i.e. Azure SQL or Cosmodb], but I would prefer not to incur the additional latency cost for storage when sending each and every message. Furthermore, I would miss any message sent by a client not using my library.

Comment: If you want to process a message _and_ store it in a data store, you will always incur additional latency as your code has to talk to the the data store. Having your library is not a bad idea for consistency.

Comment: Is there no way to use another azure service to automatically monitor and forward these messages to another store [i.e Azure SQL or Cosmosdb].  Like I mentioned previously I can use a Logic App, but the connector only works with a specific Topic and seeing I will have many topics, with new ones created as needed, that solution would be be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the intent is to save the message *sent* to the Azure Service Bus, having a catch-all subscription on each topic would be the simplest way to capture those messages. When it comes to storing those messages and where you have a variety of options. LogicApps or Azure Functions are easy to start with to capture those messages. You don't have to watch every single topic/subscription. You could use the Azure Service Bus [auto-forwarding](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/auto-forwarding) feature to send all those messages from various their respective catch-all subscriptions to a single queue and listen to that queue. Using Functions or Logic Apps you would be able to respond to those messages and store their information in any datastore you'd like. E.g. with Functions, using [output bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings), it would be very trivial to store message information in CosmosDB or Storage Table with almost no code. Any other datastore would be also possible. Example: [Azure SQL Server output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup).